# swift3 get the array in side closure

Tags: arrays, swift, escaping, closures

I would like to get the final result joblist array to use outside closure. Because I would like to setup a tableview by using Joblist array. .

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
    if error == nil && (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {

        let location2 = placemarks?[0].location

        if let location1 = self.locationManager?.location {
            let distanceInMeters = location1.distance(from: location2!)
            let IntDis = Int(distanceInMeters)
            //print(IntDis)

            if IntDis < 40000 {

                //print(address)

                if let activityid       = infoDictionary["ActivityID"] {self.newJob.ActivityID=activityid}
                if let companyname      = infoDictionary["CompanyName"] {self.newJob.CompanyName=companyname}
                if let quantity         = infoDictionary["Quantity"] {self.newJob.Quantity=quantity}
                if let coupontitle      = infoDictionary["Title"] {self.newJob.CouponTitle=coupontitle}
                if let couponterms      = infoDictionary["Terms"] {self.newJob.CouponTerms=couponterms}
                if let expirdate        = infoDictionary["ExpirDate"] {self.newJob.ExpirDate=expirdate}
                if let contactperson    = infoDictionary["ContactPerson"] {self.newJob.ContactPerson=contactperson}
                if let tel              = infoDictionary["TEL"] {self.newJob.TEL=tel}

                self.joblist.append(self.newJob)
                //print(self.joblist)
                //self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Make the `joblist` variable global so it can be accessed from multiple places
2. Use a callback, which calls a new function while passing on previously gathered data. This is especially useful when the original "data getting" proces is a network task with a delay.

Global variables:

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
var jobList = [AnyClass]() //make a global array
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
   ...filtering code ...
   joblist.append(self.newJob)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
   cell.textLabel = jobList[indexPath.row].ActivityID //or something else with the data 
}
```

Using a callback(simple version which doesn't pass on itself to the next function):

```
geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
   ...filtering code ...
   doTableViewStuff(data: joblist)
}

func doTableViewStuff(data: [Jobs]) { //or whatever type of data
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel = data[indexPath.row].ActivityID //or something else with the data 
   }
}
```

Comment: According to what you said. Do you mean Tableview will show empty record when starting and keep reloading the tableview every time when record added to tableview?

Comment: I think so yes, does my answer as posted above work for you?

Comment: keep reloading is not a good idea， because the number of row may have more than 10， it will keep reloading more than 10 times and this is what I did. That’s why I want to improve it to reload the tableview after the array finish updating.

Comment: Then use the callback approach as I explained in my question. That will trigger the reload after all the data is collected

Comment: It doesn’t work the joblist array is empty outside closure